# How to call android view's public java functions from its wrapped component of react-native?

Tags: android, react-native

[ReactEditText](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/5341ad896245c40a00b6faead1b90d01aac58f8c/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/textinput/ReactEditText.java#L75) is a wrapper around android's [EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText) and provides us [TextInput](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput). I can see in [ReactTextInputManager](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/5341ad896245c40a00b6faead1b90d01aac58f8c/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/textinput/ReactTextInputManager.java), several props are provided, which I can directly use in React Native projects.

But EditText also has an function [OnKeyListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener) which is not provided.

Is it possible to either direct call wrapped components' parent's function(OnKeyListener is public for EditText) or extend TextInput in a way that I need to wrap only this function?

Comment: PS: I am not interested in the OnKeyPress function of TextInput, it only works for soft keyboard and doesn't detect several keys like the shift key. Also, it will be great to learn if something like this is even possible.